# std::less<void> and pointer types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

`std::less<T *>` is guaranteed to provide total order, regardless of whether both pointers point into the same array.

In the latest draft of the standard, is the same true for the transparent function object `std::less<void>` (`std::less<>`) when you call its `operator()`?

Obviously, the same question applies to `std::greater`, but I assume they are specified the same.

Comment: In a sense, the question really should be "_Will the same be true_", and that's somewhat speculative.

Comment: I guess more what I'm going for is, "In the latest draft of the standard, is it true"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current draft from github does not contain any language to that effect; in fact, its definition of `less<>` says explicitly "returns `std::forward<T>(t) < std::forward<U>(u)`", which would be undefined behaviour for incomparable pointers. So... don't do it, I suppose.

If you need a heterogeneous pointer comparator, it's probably best to write your own template predicate which uses `std::less<T*>()` at the appropriate moment.

Comment: `std::less` is guaranteed to define a total order on pointer types.

Comment: The definition of `less<T>` (where T may be a pointer type) also explicitly says "`operator()` returns `x < y`." That's not a problem: it doesn't contradict the special exception "For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not." The problem is only that that special exception doesn't apply here.

Comment: @KerrekSB it is only undefined behavior for platforms in which comparing incomparable pointers via `<` is not defined by the platform.  As segmented memory model systems with fast `<` that skip the segment are rare nowadays...  The question becomes about what the *guarantee* the standard provides.

Comment: I think that if you're comparing pointers of different (unrelated) types, you're already in trouble. You could make a case for comparing `Base *` and `Derived *`, but if you're comparing `float *` and `long *` (say), I suspect that you've got other problems.

Answer (score -5):

`std::less<void>` is undefined behavior.  `std::less` requires either a pointer type (for which there is a special rule), or a type for which `<` is defined.

Comment: The question is about C++1y's diamond predicates, though.

Comment: The questions wording is a bit unfortunate. It would have been better if it said "Will the same be true for `std::less<void>`" ?